# Sending custom HTTP response code from proxy

Tags: http, https, proxy, reverse-proxy

I have a local web proxy that filters access to websites.
If the browser is attempting to access a blocked url, the proxy responds with a HTTP 302 along with a HTML page that contains a custom message.
This works fine for HTTP connections (HTTP GET). However, if the browser accesses a secured site (HTTPS using HTTP connect), a HTTP 302 response with custom message is not displayed by the browser and instead it displays a generic "This page cant be displayed" (in MSIE and equivalent in other browsers).
Is there any HTTP error code that I can return from the proxy to display a custom message to the user in the browser page?

Answer (score 0):

Yes most browsers display their own error in case of a 4xx or a 3xx response to a CONNECT request. The proxy will need to decrypt the transaction and then send a 302 in order for the page to be displayed by the browser.

Comment: I have intercepted the HTTP connect request before its forwarded to the real server. I don't want to get into a situation where I will have to be the man in the middle. Is it possible at all without allowing the initial handshake between the client/proxy/server?